# Attaching image in Civil 3D?

Tags: cad, bim

I have a recurring problem in [Civil 3D 2011](http://usa.autodesk.com/civil-3d/).  From time-to-time, I have to attach to an image file (ie - survey plan) and draft on top of it.  In the case of the current work I'm doing, I am making revisions to an existing drawing set.  That said, we need to keep the original work, so I've saved the drawings to a new folder with a new name (indicating the date of my revisions).  I have set "relative pathways" on the images I've inserted, and the drawing (technically) should go fishing for the images starting at the new save location.  When I open the drawings however, the images are missing, and all I see is a link indicating where the images "should be".

In ArcMap, this type of problem is easy to fix.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

I know this is a GIS community, but I figure some of you must use CAD too.

Comment: Sorry .... I should add that if anyone knows a similar community of CAD users I could ask, that would be appreciated too. I have this up on my AutoDesk subscription site as well, but I've not received an answer yet.

Comment: civil 3d is a gis program, this forum will do.

Comment: AutoCAD calls it a "BIM solution".  I'd say BIM is GIS related.

Comment: It also conatins Map 3d (built inside). which will re-project, import, export, clean, transform, buffer, query,... the list goes on. yeah it's a GIS.

Comment: @ Brad -- True enough. Allow me to rephase. It would have been more accurate to have said that there are many GIS professionals who don't use CAD. Civil 3D, without a doubt, is a GIS program. I guess many of you actually do use it on here, which is also good to know.

Comment: try checking out the surveyor connect forum. They use Civil 3D and CAD often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the images in the same "relative" folder with your drawing. If you save as you would need to copy the image to the new "relative" folder if you want to use relative paths.

[Relative pathways](http://www.kxcad.net/autodesk/autocad/AutoCAD_2008_Users_Guide/WS1a9193826455f5ffa23ce210c4a30acaf-5d95.htm) as far as I understand does not "fish" for locations.
It will look in the set image path, or the "relative path".
(which means the same folder location of the drawing).

To [change the path](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ffa23ce210c4a30acaf-5a9a.htm,topicNumber=d0e158717) you can use external references palette and edit the path to the correct one.

The other option is to have 1 folder location for all the images (ussually not recommended) and hard path that into your autocad profile. Or keep the images in the same "relative" folder with your drawing. If you saveas (the dwg) you would need to copy the image to the new "relative" folder if you want to use relative paths

Comment: @ Brad - Thanks.  I'm checking the link you posted now.  I just don't understand!!  All I did is save to a new folder.  Why would this break this link to my insertions?  Even the company logo is gone.  The part that confuses me most is that this issue is not "consistent".  It only happens "sometimes".  At any rate, thank you.

Comment: This is frustrating!! I followed the instructions posted by Brad, and when prompted to select the image, my command line says "not a valid reference". This would not happen in ArcMap!! Even more confusing .... the latest drawing I opened was "only" missing the logo. The survey image was in place.  In the last drawing, "all" images were missing!! I don't understand the inconsistencies. If I've made some sort of mistake I should be having the same problem in every drawing.

Comment: sometimes people insert logo images as an ole or copy/paste). There area a lot of varialbles to what you are trying to do. I have to admit that there are some things that are hard to understand. But the inconsistencies you describe are not with the software. They would be with the many different ways, formats and locations that images can be inserted as. slow down and look for the positives. negatives can always be found in anything.

Comment: I always attach to the images, unless they're georeferenced.  In this case, I aquire them via the "mapconnect" command, allowing me to work in coordinate space.  These images are sitting in a folder, and I simply attached them & adjusted the scaling.  Nothing has changed, except that I saved under a new drawing name, and I did so in a new folder within the project directory.  I appreciate the words of encouragement by the way.

Comment: On a positive thread, I start a new position in a few weeks, and will be surrounded by people with superior skills. I'm so excited!! I can't even begin to imagine the things I'll be learning on a daily basis with stronger CAD/GIS professionals around me. I'm the only CAD/GIS staffer at my current position, so I really don't have a mentor here.

Comment: Use this trick. Change the images to absolute path, saveas to your new location. Then change back to relative path.

Comment: The other option is to have 1 folder location for all the images (ussually not recommended) and hard path that into your autocad profile. Or keep the images in the same "relative" folder with your drawing. If you saveas you would need to copy the image to the new "relative" folder if you want to use relative paths.

Comment: On the latter comment (copy the images folder over) BRILLIANT!!!  I can see how that should work!!  Trying it now.  I'll be back in a minute.

Comment: That's It Brad!!  Thanks a million!!  The Logo doesn't come in on the layout (its' path is absolute, and it always resides in the same folder too).  That however, is no big deal.  I'll just insert it again on each drawing, which will only take a few seconds.  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Another option to change/repair xrefs is to use the Reference Manager. This is a standalone program that is installed as part of AutoDesk. It allows you to repair paths to external references .Think of it as the equivalent of the ArcCatalog repair functionality.

You said "... saved under a new drawing name, and I did so in a new folder within the project directory..." If this new folder has a different relative path to the images the xref will break. Check your folder nesting level. 
Also double check that the xref is using relative paths  and not a full file path. too for the DOS dots in the path name.

The conventions for specifying a relative folder path are as follows:

\       Look in the root folder of the host drawing's drive 
path        From the root folder, follow the specified path 
.\path      From the folder of the host drawing, follow the specified path 
..\path     From the folder of the host drawing, move up one folder level and follow the specified path 
....\path  From the folder of the host drawing, move up two folder levels and follow the specified path

Note If a drawing that contains referenced files is moved or saved to a different path, to a different local hard drive, or to a different network server, you must edit any relative paths to accommodate the host drawing's new location or you must relocate the referenced files.

Comment: Thanks. that's a great suggestion too. The only problem with the other solution is that I'll be creating redundencies. I'll have folders with large file sizes duplicated all over the place. I shall look into this as well.  I am very happy nonetheless.  I found a solution here for something that's been a problem for months-on-end.  You guys rock!!!